# Is there an app to read the Palm Doc format (PDB) on iOS?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, ebook

Any recommendations from actual users ?

The files are non-DRM pdb books that I have on old Toshiba e830 PocketPC.

I am specially interested in software that can handles non English encoding well (Latin2 or Win1252)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use eReader for my old PDBs on my iPhone as it's the 'official' reader put out by the same company that put out the original readers on Palm and Pocket PC devices. It works quite well for HVGA devices and is acceptable (though the text is a bit pixelated) on an iPhone 4, but as they don't have a dedicated iPad version, I would avoid using it on that device.

**edit:** Looks like I spoke too soon - eReader just released an [update](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ereader/id284499993?mt=8) today that includes a native iPad client, though it looks like we're still waiting on a retina display version.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Calibre on your desktop to convert your PDB books to ePub. See [here](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from) for the list of supported formats in Calibre.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your files to epub format (readable by Apple devices) with an online service like http://toepub.com

Answer (score -4):

You should utilize Calibrate with your computer to help alter ones PDB eBooks to help e Pub. View in this article with the directory helped codecs with Calibrate.

Comment: I think you mean Calibre as explained in another answer - also your grammar needs changing as it is difficult to understand this answer